# LAN map for Mac OS X

Tags: software-recommendation, network

I'm looking for a program that will create a visual map of my home network, I've found [**lanmap**](http://www.parseerror.com/lanmap/) but it requires too many programs to be installed to be able to run.

Does anyone knows a native Mac app for the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iNet for Mac is avail­able for down­load at the App­Store. It is a native osx app that shows you what your mac is connected to.

Comment: iNet is a great iOS app. Nice to see it in the Mac App Store. The interface looks really great from the screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [nmap](http://nmap.org/) with the zenmap GUI. It's normally a port scanner but it creates visual maps of what you scan.